# How I may avoid making spaghetti code while trying to ask user for permissions?

Tags: java, android, permissions

Could you explain me, how I should do this right way? I've find this nonsense at all. So I'm trying to make an "welcome screen" where user will be asked for grant some location permissions. Before I've deleted everything and started once again, and faced same problem again - When user already grant the permission, the code from **FusedLocationProviderClient** still want to check if the permissions are granted(!) Is there something I doing wrong? Look at some example:

```
String[] mPermissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
FusedLocationProviderClient mClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_screen);
    mClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    checkPermissions();
}

private void checkPermissions() {
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, mPermissions)) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    Activity#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        //TODO
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, @NonNull List<String> perms) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    Activity#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, @NonNull List<String> perms) {}
```

How I may make it work without multiple asking for permissions at once?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but from what I understood:

If you don't want it to check for permissions after they have been granted, you could make a boolean hasPermission and before calling the method to check, add an if statement.

if(!hasPermission)
checkPermissions();

Inside the checkPermissions method, if it detects that the permissions have been granted, you just set hasPermission = true and it will not check again because the if condition will no longer be true.

Comment: Better to ask for more clarifications if the question isn't clear enough.